# How can I update my company info for my Facebook apps? I need to update the PayPal account

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits

How can I update my company info for my Facebook apps? I need to update the PayPal account. In edit settings for our app ther is no option to 'update company info'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to contact the Facebook Credits Developer Support team here: http://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=204456519570236